# maven - several root poms

Tags: java, maven

My project structure is like that

```
├── biz
│   └── biz-pom.xml
├── new-pom.xml
└── pom.xml
```

I want to build my project with `new-pom.xml`, I run `mvn -f new-pom.xml clean deploy` but find `biz-pom.xml` is relied on deploy config  in `pom.xml` instead of `new-pom.xml`.
Any one has an idea?

Comment: This is a very unusual construction. I would try to get rid of one of the POMs. Could you explain why you have two different POMs? Maybe we then find a better solution for your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [Maven – Parent and Child POM Example](https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/#parent-relative-path):

> #### Parent POM Relative Path
>
> By default, Maven looks for the parent POM first at project’s root, then the local repository, and lastly in the remote repository. If parent POM file is not located in any other place, then you can use code tag. This **relative path shall be relative to project root**.
>
> > The relative path, if not given explicitly, defaults to `..`, i.e. the pom in the parent directory of the current project.
>
> ```xml
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>
>     <!--The identifier of the parent POM-->
>     <parent>
>         <groupId>com.howtodoinjava.demo</groupId>
>         <artifactId>MavenExamples</artifactId>
>         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <relativePath>../baseapp/pom.xml</relativePath>
>     </parent>
>
>     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>     <artifactId>MavenExamples</artifactId>
>     <name>MavenExamples Child POM</name>
>     <packaging>jar</packaging>
>
> </project>
> ```

So to have `biz-pom.xml` use `new-pom.xml`, you have to specify that using the `<relativePath>` element inside the `<parent>` element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need to build my project with two different environments(same process). So I use two root pom rather than relativePath. Any ideas?

Comment: @Wzzzz Then maybe [**Build Profiles**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: As I said above: Please add background information to the question. It is rather likely that we find a better solution for your problem than using two different POMs. The better solution could e.g. be using profiles or properties.